# Passing multiple parameters from View to a RelayCommand inside a ViewModel, .net MAUI

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui, maui-community-toolkit

Can you help me with correct implementation of mvvm commands via `RelayCommand`? If I pass more than one parameter there (like button and page for animation), an error appears, because there is no proper constructor.

I decided to set the command (`RelayCommand`) directly on the page (view), and call from there method (that in view model).

```
[RelayCommand]
public async Task PlayMusic()
{
    await gamePageViewModel.PlayMusic(MusicButton, SoundImg);
}
```

Can you tell me how to solve this architectural problem?

Comment: A Command shouldn't have any visibility on Views. Doing that is an architectural mistake. A command should be placed *only* in the view model and contain the code to execute, for example, when a button is clicked. Of course you can pass parameters, but from your example it doesn't seem to me that you need any. Can you please explain what you're trying to do from a higher level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Maui MultiBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/multibinding?view=net-maui-7.0) for CommandParameter.

Suppose we implement a Button Command which has two parameters, from the Text Property of two labels,

```
<Button
    x:Name="CounterBtn"
    Text="Click me"      
    Command="{Binding ClickedCommand}">
    <Button.CommandParameter>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Myconverter}">
            <Binding Path="Text" Source="{x:Reference label1}" />
            <Binding Path="Text" Source="{x:Reference label2}" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Button.CommandParameter>
```

We could define our MultiBindingConverter called Myconverter, which implememts [IMultiValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/multibinding?view=net-maui-7.0#define-a-imultivalueconverter). For how to consume the MultiValueConverter, you may refer to [Consume a IMultiValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/multibinding?view=net-maui-7.0#consume-a-imultivalueconverter)

```
public class MyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // this values return all command parameters
        return values;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then in viewModel, we can get all parameters

```
    [RelayCommand]
    public async void Clicked(object Parameter)
    {
        var param = Parameter as object[];
        var text1 = param[0];
        var text2 = param[1];
```